# What is the x and y axis showing for this matplotlib.pyplot histogram of a .wav file?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, histogram, wav, amplitude

The code below generates a histogram from a .wav file, but what exactly does the histogram show? Is the x axis amplitude binned by sampling rate? Is the y axis a count of how many samples are in each amplitude bin? And how is amplitude calculated?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   
Fs, data = wavfile.read('audio file') 

plt.hist(data, bins = 'auto')  
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you plot the `histogram`, the "x" is the "y" bins (the y gets quantized), and the "y" is the counts, meaning the number of elements that have y values in the bin range. Each bin overs a different range of y, and the histogram counts up the number of elements in that range.

According to this excellent [article](https://www.testandmeasurementtips.com/the-difference-between-histograms-and-spectrograms-faq/).

> A histogram basically depicts an estimate of the probability
> distribution of some variable. To construct a histogram, the range of
> possible variable values gets divided into a series of intervals
> called bins. The bins must be adjacent to each other and are often
> (but necessarily) of equal width. Then a count of how many values fall
> into each interval determines the height of each bin such that the
> height is proportional to the number of cases in each bin. A histogram
> may also be normalized to display “relative” frequencies. It then
> shows the proportion of cases that fall into each of several
> categories, with the sum of the heights equaling one.

You can find more detailed information here @ `matplotlib` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html).

If you still have a doubt, I found a very good video series on YouTube by [Valerio Velardo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCwMQJnKk2c&list=PL-wATfeyAMNqIee7cH3q1bh4QJFAaeNv0) and you can find all the slides and codes are [here](https://github.com/musikalkemist/AudioSignalProcessingForML).

Comment: Thank you, that's my understanding of what a histogram is. But how is the audio signal represented in it? What kind of data are in the bins? Amplitude? Frequency?